# Call a java method in R using rJava

Tags: java, r, rjava

I use rJava to call a java code from R, trying  to call an algorithm from [SPMF](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=download.php) tool. I tried to use a wrapper function as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667379/call-java-from-r), but this did not work with the [SPMF](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=download.php) code.

this is my R code:

```
   library(rJava)
   .jinit()
   .jaddClassPath ( "C:/mydrive/eclipse-workspace/myfile/src")
   print(.jclassPath())
   obj <- .jnew("AlgoFPGrowth_Strings")
   s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig= "V", method="runAlgorithm", 
   "input.csv","output.txt") ,  0.4 )
```

it gives me error ,method runAlgorithm with signature (D)V not found

this is the main in java:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AlgoFPGrowth_Strings fpwindow=new AlgoFPGrowth_Strings();
    String input="input.csv";
    String output="output.txt";
    double minsupp = 0.4; 
    fpwindow.runAlgorithm( input,  output,  minsupp);
    fpwindow.printStats();

}
```

I tried to change  returnSig value into S and Ljava/lang/String; but I got the same error, could not find the method

when I apply the code on different java code with simple method it works, is there any idea how can I change my code?

Comment: A user of the Java library has an example of providing an R interface to some of the algorithms https://github.com/pommedeterresautee/spmf

Comment: thanks for your reply, I already extracted one algorithm from this tool and used it alone, I believe the problem is in the returnSig but I could not fix it. Is  there any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below methods,

1. Change your `jclassPath`, where you directly specify the complete pathname of your jar file including the jar name, say `/home/user/mypath/myclass_name.jar`
2. Or, you can unzip your jar file in a folder and refer to that path in your `jclassPath`.

If, the above does not work,

3. Try to write the 'runAlgorithm' method in the same class where you are calling. I have faced issues with calling external libraries/classes.